# Excel - array, offset-associated cell

Tags: excel

I have a challenge that seems like it should have an easy answer, but I cannot solve it. I have a list of rates which I need to find the smallest value in a large list if the criteria matches three other cells (one cell equals, next cell greater than, next cell less than) and my formula is:

```
=IF(C7="f",IF(MIN(IF($C$4:$C$43="m",IF($D$4:$D$43>E7,IF($D$4:$D$43<F7,$G$4:$G$43,""),""),""))>0,MIN(IF($C$4:$C$43="m",IF($D$4:$D$43>E7,IF($D$4:$D$43<F7,$G$4:$G$43,""),""),"")),"no match"),"")
```

It has extra in it so it does not do anything if it does not meet the "f" criteria and it returns "no match" if the criteria is no met in the array.

This part works, but now I want to display a cell name from same rate associated to the rate found (name of rate), beside the rate found in formula above, hence similar formula but using INDEX and MATCH or OFFSET.  The challenge is my data has rates that are the same, hence the array can return multiple correct answers, again this is okay, but when I try to match it to the rate name, it simply finds the first rate in the array that matches rate without the criteria and I can not figure out how to incorporate the criteria again.

In others words - the criteria finds the correct match, but the match then looks up the value and chooses the first match in array- not correct always.  Below is a sample of the data.
[sorry about the image- no easy way to show data in SO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVdf0.jpg)

Comment: So you only want M values to be found? If so add that as an argument in an IF function.

Comment: I believe in the formula above your `<` and `>` are reversed and you need to put `=` after them.  Those changes were needed to get the returns on the first column as per your example.

Comment: the equal sign is correct, my < and > where correct, but the sample data i provided had the low and high opposite of my actual data - oops- hence the formula below is awesome- but I had to reverse the < and > to make it work. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array formula will return the correct name and does not rely on your other formula's return:

```
=IF(C4="f",IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$B$43,MATCH(MIN(IF(($C$4:$C$43="m")*($D$4:$D$43<=E4)*($D$4:$D$43>=F4),$G$4:$G$43)),IF(($C$4:$C$43="m")*($D$4:$D$43<=E4)*($D$4:$D$43>=F4),$G$4:$G$43),0)),"No Match"),"")
```

being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]